# How to allocate a resident memory?

Tags: go

I found after `b := make([]byte,4096000000)`, the allocated memory is virtual memory, I want to mark them as RES(physical memory usage as seen in top ), how to do this?

`rand.Read(b)` is very slow.

Comment: Fill it in a loop with a constant value?

Comment: Wow, thank you, It worked. I didn't expect slow because rand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use at least one byte in each page. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    b := make([]byte, 2*1024*1024*1024)
    fmt.Println(len(b))
    pagesize := os.Getpagesize()
    for i := 0; i < 60; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(b); j += pagesize {
            b[j] = 42
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2147483648
```

top:

```
RES 2.1g
```

Comment: Isn't this solution - while working - heavily OS dependent? An OS with a different memmgmt strategy might immediately swap out pages. Also, the results could be different, if memory gets sparse.

Comment: @thst: "`RES` (physical memory usage as seen in `top`)." `man top`: top - display Linux processes. The question is a Linux question.

Comment: Don't want to fight on this issue :-) but top can hardly be called an exclusive linux tool and maybe linux changes/changed the mem-management between different plattforms or kernels. As long as you cannot enforce a special type of memory for a byte array, you cannot guarantee, that the memory is still "in RAM" some minutes of idleness later. I wouldn't link any vital production function to this :-) BUT ... if the op is happy with this solution, that's fine with me. Learned a hack for a future situation at least ;-)

Comment: Thank you, Learned what is page now. And there's a func `os.Getpagesize()` returns the underlying system's memory page size.